# Logstash, how to handle a field with sub fields

Tags: logstash

I have a message log which is parsed ok via:

```
filter {
  kv {
    field_split => "|"
  }
```

But one field sometimes has subfields delimited by a utf8 char.

```
AppBody=POIREQ:¸ID: 27¸Address: http://myserver¸Payload: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <xml here...>
```

Here it does not, and goes straight to xml string:

```
AppBody=POIRESP:<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Header><xml here....>
```

So I guess AppBody=TYPE
Then either

```
:<soap:Evnvelope ....
```

Or:

```
¸ID: 27¸ ... <?xml version ....
```

Struggling with how to handle these subfields.  I'd be ok to make them 'normal' fields.
but what I really need, is to separate out the xml into its own field.

The mutate filter only appears to work on fields?
Is there a sed like mutator, before fields are parsed via kv ?

Answer (score 1):

Could you perhaps just run a second kv filter?

```
filter {
  kv {
    field_split => "|"
  }
  kv {
    field_split => "¸"
    value_split => ":"
    source => "AppBody"
  }
}
```

The second kv block now splits the subfields found inside the `AppBody` field.